# UIImageView not resizing as circle and UILabel not resizing within StackView and Custom Collection Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to resize my `UIImageView` as a circle, however; every time I try to resize the `UIImageView`, which is inside a StackView along with the `UILabel`, I keep on ending up with a more rectangular shape. Can someone show me where I am going wrong I have been stuck on this for days? Below is my code, and what it's trying to do is add the image with the label at the bottom, and the image is supposed to be round, and this is supposed to be for my collection view controller.

**custom collection view cell**

```
import UIKit

class CarerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "CarerCollectionViewCell"
    
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20);
        //imageView.center = imageView.superview!.center;
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height / 2
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private let carerNamelabel: UILabel = {
        let carerNamelabel = UILabel()
        carerNamelabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
        carerNamelabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        carerNamelabel.textAlignment = .center
        carerNamelabel.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50);
        return carerNamelabel
    }()
    
    private let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureContentView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    private func configureContentView() {
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        stackView.clipsToBounds = true
        carerNamelabel.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        configureStackView()
    }
    
    private func configureStackView() {
        allContraints()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(carerNamelabel)
    }
    
    private func allContraints() {
        setStackViewConstraint()
    }
    
    private func setStackViewConstraint() {
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    
    
    public func configureImage(with imageName: String, andImageName labelName: String) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        carerNamelabel.text = labelName
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        stackView.frame = contentView.bounds
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageView.image = nil
        carerNamelabel.text = nil
    }
}
```

Below here is my code for the CollectionViewControler

**custom collection view**

```
import UIKit

class CarerViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(CarerCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarerCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // Layout constraints for `collectionView`
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: 600),
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CarerCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CarerCollectionViewCell
        cell.configureImage(with: "m7opt04g_ms-dhoni-afp_625x300_06_July_20", andImageName: "IMAGE NO. 1")
        return cell
    }
}
```

Can somebody show or point to me what I am doing wrong, thank you
[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWEbi.png)

Comment: try to move your resize code to the viewWillApear method.

Answer (score 0):

`UIStackView` could be tricky sometimes, you can embed your `UIImageView` in a `UIView`, and move your layout code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`, this also implys for the `UILabel` embed that also inside a `UIView`, so the containers `UIView`s will have a static frame for the `UIStackView`to be layout correctly and whats inside them will only affect itself.